# How can I retrieve and save images with non-standard basenames using PHP

Tags: php, html, image, dom

**Short version** 
When I try to run file_get_contents() with this link, 'http://s1.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20131205&t=2&i=817503382&w=&fh=&fw=&ll=700&pl=378&r=CBRE9B401AG00', it returns: "illegal: d - msg". Why is it that file_get_contents() works on most image link but not this one, and how can I make it work?

**Details**
Part of my webapp's functionality is to parse external html files for images, then allow the user to select a desired image, and automatically save a reduced-size version of the image to my server. My code works for 99% of cases, but for the remaining 1% I am unable to successfully get the image file onto my server in order to re-size it. The cases that don't work seem to all involve html  elements with 'src' attributes that look like this:

http://s1.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20131205&t=2&i=817503382&w=&fh=&fw=&ll=580&pl=378&r=CBRE9B401AG00

as opposed to a more standard image path such as this:

http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/wiredscience/2013/12/keyes-wd.jpg

Below is the code that I use in order to get and save the external image once the user has selected it, where the variable $newFileName is equal to an img path string such as the ones pasted above:

```
    $contentOrFalseOnFailure   = file_get_contents($newFileName);        
    $byteCountOrFalseOnFailure = file_put_contents($filenameOut, $contentOrFalseOnFailure);
    $fileName = basename($newFileName);
    $fileTmpLoc = $filenameOut;
    $fileSize = $byteCountOrFalseOnFailure;       
    $fileExt = pathinfo($fileTmpLoc, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);

    if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
            header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: That image has no dimensions");
    exit(); 
    }
```

When the  src is non-standard, the script doesn't make it beyond this point, ie i get the "That image has no dimestions" error. What can I do to save save these non-standard images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in JUST the image dimensions and nothing else about it, you could go with GD's [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) without needing a temp on-disk file:

```
$img = file_get_contents($url);

$gd = imagecreatefromstring($img);

$width = imagesx($gd);
$height = imagesy($gd);
```

This has the downside of having to decompress the image into memory, however. You'd have to hope that the remote server doesn't sent over a ludicriously dimensioned image that doesn't exceed the PHP memory_limit upon decompression.

Comment: i need more than the image dimension, I am trying to actually save the image onto my server.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the URL, look at the `Content-Type` header in the response.

Comment: Are you suggesting looking at the Content-Type as a means of getting the file extension? If so, that is not my main problem. My problem is that the file_get_contents() method does not work in the first place.

Comment: @MartínMolina The content-type header has nothing to do with the file name extension, and the file name extension (if it exists) has nothing to do with the content type.  Don't confuse the two.  Just because a lot of images end in .jpg and .png doesn't mean they have to.  This is a convention, and one that doesn't really apply to HTTP anyway.  Don't use `file_get_contents()` use cURL and then you can access all the response headers.